# Integrating MySQL or SQL in an ios app

Tags: mysql, ios, xcode

I am building a ios app for ipad, in which the user will be able to create a personal page, by adding in a view controller lavels, images, and text fields... I then wanted to offer the share option, so that the content is saved online and shared amongs all app users. This is where i am getting a bit confused. At first i thought of using icloud, but this was not possible. So i looked on the internet, and found out of this mySQL, but after all the research i still can not understand how it works. So I have at first to create a mysql or sql (don't know the difference), on a mac or pc, and then integrate using a firmware my server in the app. Am i right? Is this how you do it? Can someone explain me? Also, has this anything to do with XML?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure about the setup, but SQL is a common software for databases, holding information. SQL is the language, MYSQL is one of the databases. If you can set up a server somewhere and connect to it via the app, you can go from there. Check out XAMPP (installs a bunch of srver software, including mysql, on your computer) for setting up one on your computer to do some testing before committing to a paid server.

Comment: This is an extremely broad question. You could read entire books on the subject and barely breach the surface. I don't think anyone is going to be able to satisfactorily explain all of server-side web and database development in a single StackOverflow question; you'll have to perform some independent research and come back here with specific questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow - it's hard to know where to start, but let me dive in.

SQL is the language that MySQL uses - MySQL is a database management system, which is free, similar to Microsoft's SQL Server and Oracle's Oracle DBMS, which are not. All database management systems are good places to store data for quick and flexible retrieval.

If you want your iOS app to access data shared across users, then you'll need to build (1) the database, (2) a server-side application that runs on a server that can access that database, and (3) an interface in your iOS app to talk to your server application.

The iOS app talks to your users on their iPhone. That app will talk to the server application you write to do things to the database. The database will only talk to the server application you wrote.

This is quite ambitious, but there are lots of books and websites that will tell you how to do each of these things. However, you have a lot of decisions to make about what languages and platforms to use to build all the different pieces. My advice is to pick platforms close to what you know.

And, no, this has nothing to do with XML - unless you want to use that somewhere among all the applications you are going to be writing. You can use anything to transfer information from your server side application to your iOS app - JSON, XML, even plain text. Since you'll be both reading it (in your iOS app) and writing it (in your server application), you'll have complete control over how to format it and what it all means.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes thanks!  I will try to look up tutorials for each of the points you made